# the menu issue, does not appear on the mobile

Tags: html, css

The menu on your pc looks like this, that is, you see, see the picture below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpKsR.jpg

And on the mobile, the menu is not visible, only the logo and the rest of the page are visible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe21w.jpg

```css
nav{
 width: 1330px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

nav ul li{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="logo-cont"></div>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Servicii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cere ofertă</a></li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   width: 1330px;
```

Try out:

```
  width: 100%;
```

And look what happens

Comment: And the text in the menu, how can I make it not to be underlined? Like we put text-descrition: none; and it does not work.

Comment: text-decoration and not text-descrition

Comment: nav ul li a{ text-decoration: none;}